# questions about Seam Conversation Context

Tags: jboss, seam, seam2

Supposing that I'm using the `@Begin` annotation to start a long-term conversation, which of the following statement is correct:

1. if method returned normally, Seam destroys the current temporal conversation and create a new conversation which is long-term.
2. if method returned normally, Seam promotes the current temporal conversation to a long-term conversation.

According to "*Practical JBoss Seam Projects*", the first statement is right. But in Seam Reference-2.3.0, it says:
"When an `@Begin` method is encountered, the temporary conversation context is promoted to a long running conversation."

I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second statement is correct: Seam promotes the temporary conversation to a long-term one.